# Rotate 3 div simultaneously using css

Tags: css, rotation

I want to rotate 3 div simultaneously.

```
<img src="logo.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
<img src="1.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
<img src="2.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
```

All these three images are to rotated whn mouse move on any one of them.The Css used is

```
  .logo {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .logo:hover {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

Comment: Sounds good. Have you got anything so far?

Comment: But the code i got only rotates the uppermost image not all of them. So, can i rotate all of them using css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap all of your images in another div, and then apply the hover pseudoclass to that instead.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="logo.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
  <img src="1.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
  <img src="2.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }
 #wrap:hover .logo {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NbzrV/

Comment: Won't that rotate the whole div, so the order of the images is changed?

Comment: @snipes83 No, it applies the rotation to the images themselves.

Comment: Nah, notice the `#wrap:hover .logo` selector. When `#wrap` is hovered, rotate all `.logo` children

Comment: @ChristianVarga Ahh, neat. Didn't know that.

Comment: @ChristianVarga btw thanx 4 the help bro.

Comment: No worries mate, you'd just need to add different IDs or classes to the images, then target them individually (`#wrap:hover #logo1 { }`, `#wrap:hover #logo2{ }` etc). I made a demo in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NbzrV/1/

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .logo {
      -moz-transform:rotate(10deg); //firefox
      -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg); //Chrome, Safari
      -o-transform:rotate(10deg); //Opera
      }

  .logo:hover {
              -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); //firefox
              -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); //Chrome, Safari
              -o-transform:rotate(45deg); //Opera
              }


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the images in a container, then apply the rotation to images in a hovered container:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
    <img src="1.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
    <img src="2.png" class="logo" width="150px" height="150px"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .logo {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  #container:hover .logo {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```